# Is the undocumented activity "com.android.settings.ProxySelector" still there in Android 5.0?

Tags: android, undocumented-behavior

I can bring up the undocumented `ProxySelector` activity by the following code:

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.ProxySelector"));

startActivity(intent);
```

I have tested on some devices (Galaxy S3 and S4 using Android 4.3 and 4.4), and this activity works fine,
but after upgrading the Galaxy S4 to Android 5.0, the activity didn't show up. Instead, a "Unfortunately, Settings has stopped" message was shown.

Is this undocumented activity still supported on Android 5, like it was on 4.3 and 4.4? If so, how can I use it? I want it so that I can easily set a global HTTP proxy.

Comment: No, my question is different.